# How Is Laplacian of Gaussian (LoG) Implemented as Four 1D Convolutions?

Tags: image-processing, filters, gaussian, separability

I am trying to understand the four 1D convolution operations involved in implementation of `Laplacian of Gaussian(LoG)`. I have read the answers to [What Is the Difference between Difference of Gaussian, Laplace of Gaussian, and Mexican Hat Wavelet?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/47909/34620), and I am also reading [ME5286 - Lecture 7 (2017) - Edge Detection](https://www.scribd.com/document/490915515) (See slide# 62 and 63). My current understanding is:

1. Pre-compute `LoG` and separate to 1D filters in x and y: `gxx(x)` and `gyy(y)`.
2. Take Gaussian (`g`) and separate to: `g(x)` and `g(y)`.
3. First apply `g(y)` and `gyy(y)` to the image. That makes two 1D convolutions.
4. Then apply `g(x)` to the result from `gyy(y)` and `gxx(x)` to the result from `g(y)`. That adds two more 1D convolutions, making the total four.

**Questions:**

1. Is the above understanding correct?
2. How is this same as `LoG`?
3. Also, the diagram in slide #62 contradicts slide #63, in the [pdf](https://www.scribd.com/document/490915515) (Saad J. Bedros - ME5286 Lecture 7 2017 Edge Detection). Which one is correct?

**Edit:**

It's actually slide#61 and slide#62.

**Edit2:**

Please see the very last comment, posted Dec 19, 2018, on the first answer.

Comment: Slide #62 is terrible. It not only switches some x-es and y-s around, but it also shows $\Delta^2$ where it should say $\nabla^2$ (noting that $\Delta = \nabla^2$ is the Laplace operator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Chris Luengo](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/33605/cris-luengo)'s [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/47909/128) is perfect.
The trick is that you can calculate the 2nd derivative of the image (Using Finite Differences -> Convolution) and then blur it with Gaussian Filter.
Since both are seperable kernels you can do that by 4 1D convolutions.

If the input image is given by `I`

1. Calculate `Ixx` (The 2nd derivative on `x` direction) using convolution.
2. Filter `Ixx` with 1D Gaussian Kernel along the `x` direction.

Do the above for the `y` direction as well.
The `LoG` image is the sum of both.

To answer your questions:

1. See my explanation above. I think it matches your understanding.
2. This is the very definition (The Discrete) of the `LoG`.
3. I don't see the contradiction between #62 and #63.

Comment: But isn't slide #62 saying `LoG = gyy * gx + gy * gxx` while slide #63 is saying `LoG = gxx * gx + gyy * gy`? The terms that are getting added up are different because individual terms that are getting multiplied form different combinations.

Comment: For what I see #62 says the log is the sum of 1D filtered 2nd Derivative of the image. Slide #63 only mentions the Separability property of the Gaussian Kernel.

Comment: @ I am talking about the diagrams at the bottom of slide #62 and #63.

Comment: Could it be that you're talking about #61 and #62?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. My bad. I will make an edit in the question.

Comment: I think he author just wanted to show that since all operations are Linear and Spatially Invariant you can do them in any order and combination you want. So you can do differentiation on `x` with Blur on `y` and the other way around and sum and the result is the same.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to confirm.

Comment: Update: The slide #61 is correct. The slide #62 actually has a small correction. It should be `gxx(y) * g(x) + gyy(x) * g(y)`, NOT `gxx(x) * g(x) + gyy(y) * g(y)`.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to compute the Laplace of Gaussian operator:

1. As [Royi suggests](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/51986/33605), by computing
   $f * \nabla^2 * g$,where we take the operator $\nabla^2$ as a convolution kernel created using the finite difference approximation to the derivative.
2. As [the slides linked by OP](http://www.me.umn.edu/courses/me5286/vision/VisionNotes/2017/ME5286-Lecture7-2017-EdgeDetection2.pdf) suggest, by computing
   $$
   f * \nabla^2 g = f * \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}g+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}g\right) = f * g_{xx} + f * g_{yy}
   $$

**Approach 1** is computationally cheaper: convolution with the Gaussian $g$ is separable, and thus takes two 1D convolutions. The discrete Laplace operator is a 3x3 matrix, this third convolution is cheap to compute.

**Approach 2** is more precise: it doesn't use any discrete approximations to the derivative, instead using a sampled Gaussian derivative as a kernel. This approach takes two convolutions (which are both separable into two 1D convolutions, for a total of four 1D convolutions) and an addition. Note that there is one extra intermediate image to deal with, it uses more memory.

**Approach 1:** convolve image with $g(x)$, then with $g(y)$, then with the discrete 3x3 Laplace kernel.

**Approach 2:** convolve image with $g(x)$, then with $g_{yy}(y)$, store result; convolve image with $g(y)$ then with $g_{xx}(x)$; sum the two results.